# How can I use WHERE clause in this SQL query?

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have two tables - Customers and Orders.  Customers just contains an ID and the name.  Orders contains an Order ID, a Customer ID, and the amount of the Order.   My goal is to sum the orders for each customer,even  for customers who didn't have any orders (so, a 0 in the result set).

**Problem** I actually need to show only the entries for which the total for each customer id < 500.  I have a WHERE clause for this, but I get an error.

```
SELECT * FROM orders;
SELECT * FROM customer;

SELECT
    c.customer_id, c.customer_name, ISNULL(sum(o.order_total),0) as grand_total
FROM
    customer c
LEFT JOIN
    orders o
ON
    c.customer_id = o.customer_id
--WHERE
    --grand_total < 500
GROUP BY
    c.customer_id, c.customer_name
ORDER BY
    grand_total
```

---

[image]

I was able to do this with a LEFT JOIN,and have the Customers table on the "left", to get every customer, and to show a 0 when they had no orders.  I aliased the sums of each order (by customer) as grand_total.
When I use grand_total in and ORDER_BY, the alias is recognized, and the grand_total column sorts as expected.  But when I reference the grand_total alias in my WHERE statement (i.e.  WHERE grand_total < 500), I get the error **Invalid column name 'grand_total'**

I'm confused as to why grand_total is recognized in the ORDER_BY but not the WHERE.   Aside from that, I'm trying to find the right syntax for a WHERE clause to include only the rows for which grand_total < 500.

Comment: Search for HAVING clause.

Comment: Tip for future questions, though it looks like you're using sql server, always explicitly include your dbms in the question tags as syntax can vary by vendor and version.

Comment: Yes, good point on the dbms.  Only after experimenting with MySQL vs. MSSQL vs. PostgreSQL do I realize the volume of syntax differences, even if only subtle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HAVING` for filtering groups, not `WHERE`:

```
SELECT
    c.customer_id,
    c.customer_name,
    COALESCE(sum(o.order_total), 0) as grand_total
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING COALESCE(sum(o.order_total), 0) < 500
ORDER BY 3
```

Since you didn't specify which database you're using, I changed ISNULL to COALESCE and used the actual expression in HAVING, which makes it totally portable.

Also made use of column *numbers* in GROUP BY and ORDER BY rather than repeating expressions to make the query easier on the eyes.

Comment: I wanted to upvote, but I need some credentials apparently.  Anyway, I appreciate the help. Removing the WHERE and including the HAVING was the answer, as you mentioned.   After doing that, the ISNULL works, but if COALESCE is more flexible, I'll go that route.  Interestingly, I had to switch back to using c.customer_id and c.customer_name (in lieu of 1,2) in the GROUP BY.  When I tried GROUP BY 1, 2, I got an error:  "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference", which is def over my head.  One more note: it DOES let me use column # 3 in ORDER BY

Comment: @DanielT - IIRC, some databases like SQL Server, don't allow you to GROUP BY ordinals i.e. 1 = first column, 2 = second column, etc...